# Restlet - Connection Problems - 406 Not Acceptable - Plain Text

Tags: rest, jersey, restlet

couldnt find somewhere else advice.

I am writing a Restlet JSE Client for a Jersey(!) Restful Service. I already wrote a Jersey client for that and it is working, so the jersey service is alright. Now I get problems in writing a restlet client:

My Service root adress is:

```
 http://localhost:8080/com-project-core/rest, so I call:

 ClientResource = service = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8080/com-project-core/rest");
```

My Basic Auth Credentiels are admin and xxx, so I call:

```
 service.setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, "admin", "xxx");
```

Now the problems:

```
 ClientResource service = new ClientResource("http://localhost:8080/com-project-core/rest/ping");
```

calls up my service. After that I try

```
 String myString = service.get(String.class);
 System.out.println(myString);
```

I get a:

```
 08.07.2012 17:41:48 org.restlet.engine.http.connector.HttpClientHelper start
 INFO: Starting the default HTTP client
```

in my output. Not more! The Junit Test says:

```
 Not Acceptable (406) - Not Acceptable
```

So he can find the resource but cannot produce @Produces("text/plain") ??

So when I remove @Produces("text/plain") on server side it works!!

For the resourcey my server side looks like this:

```
    @Path("/ping")
    @RolesAllowed({"admin", "user"})
    public class ConnectedResourceBean implements ConnectedResourceIF {

        @GET
        @Produces("text/plain")
        public String getPingMessage() throws NamingException {             

        return "Hello World";
       }
 }
```

For my pom in set this dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
    <version>${restlet.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.xstream</artifactId>
    <version>${restlet.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

As I said, its working with my jersey client.

Comment: What did you try to do with myString? If you don't print it, you won't see it...

Comment: i did it:System.out.println(myString);

Comment: Do you see the request coming in to the server side?

Comment: No, theres is nothing... But with my jersey client I used the same URI.

Comment: Maybe another hint: the junit test says: Not Acceptable (406) - Not Acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way: Restlet had problems with

```
 @Produces("text/plain")
```

on jersey server side. Can someone explain me that fact?

Edit:

Made it work with

```
 <properties>
     <restlet.version>2.1-M3</restlet.version>
 </properties>
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that someone forgets to send an `Accept:` header.

Comment: No idea. I've never even heard of either Jersey or Restlet. All I know is that a 406 error means that the incoming `Accept:` header doesn't include the outgoing `Content-Type`'s value.